# Sending error message for rejected URI input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to clean up URLs inserted into a Rails app using URI. This works great for getting down to the root url, but if someone enters something that's not a URL, it breaks.

How can I modify it to send back an error message asking for a valid URL?

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
require 'uri'

validates :name, :url, presence: true

before_validation :clean_url
validates_uniqueness_of :url

def clean_url
    url = self.url.downcase # Make it lowercase first

    url = URI(url).host

    if url[0..2] == "www"
        url = url.delete_prefix("www.")
    end

    self.url = url
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: URLs are case-sensitive, FYI. `url.downcase` may be a bad idea. You also haven't really indicate what kinds of error's you're trying to catch and prevent, but the answer will ultimately involve adding a validation method that uses `self.errors`

Comment: Deleting the `www` subdomain is another bad idea. You will break links when you reconstruct it into a url.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sanitizing the URL before validation, I would sanitize the URL in the validation step with a [custom validation method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) and record an error message when the sanitation fails:

```
validate :urls_is_valid_and_sanitized

private

def urls_is_valid_and_sanitized
  return unless url.present?

  host = URI(url.downcase).host

  if host
    self.url = host.delete_prefix("www.")
  else
    errors.add(:url, "must include a hostname")
  end
rescue URI::InvalidURIError => e
  errors.add(:url, "is invalid")
end
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the error message says "Url has already been taken" for some reason instead of "URL is invalid"

Comment: You have another validation in that model: `validates_uniqueness_of :url` That means that each URL must be unique in the whole system. Obviously you try to enter an URL that already exists in the database.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, that error is popping up even though the URL is unique but isn't a proper URL. So when I try to enter "hello" as a URL, the error I get is "Url has already been taken" instead of getting "URL is invalid"

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that an URL can be valid but might not include a hostname. I updated my answer to address that issue.